# Pass input to url parameters in angular 2

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, httprequest, angular-cli

I'm trying to pass an input from angular2 to a url parameter on a get request to retrieve data from my database. I've looked everywhere to see if anyone else has done this and while they have passed objects as parameters I'm not sure if that is what I need to do.

here's some code..

This is my backend express route to retrieve data from my mongodb.

```
 app.get('/displayorders/:showOrder', function (req, res) {
    db.woocommerceorders.findOne({ id: req.params.showOrders }, function 
 (err, data) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }res.send(data);
    });
 })
```

This is my service in angular2 to retrieve data from my mongodb.

```
displayOrders(showOrders) {
var displayedOrders;
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/displayorders/:' + showOrders)
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

This is my front end click event to retrieve the desired parameter from the input and pass it as a parameter on my url string.

```
onFindOrderById(showOrders) {
this.woocommerceService.displayOrders(showOrders)
  .subscribe(
  data => this.showOrders = JSON.stringify(data),
  error => alert(error),
  () => console.log('Displaying Order By Id')
  );
}
```

This is my html used to take the input and pass it to my click event function.

```
<div class="form-group container bottom-border">
<button type="button" class="btn displaybutton" 
(click)="onFindOrderById(showOrders)">Click To Retrieve</button>

<br><br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input class="form-control col-xs-6" [(ngModel)]="showOrders"  
placeholder="Input Id Number">
        <p><b>Retrieved Order:</b></p> <div>{{showOrders}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if I should try a post request instead? I feel as though this should be straight forward but right now I keep getting an error of UNEXPECTED END OF JSON ENDPOINT. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure about the : in the url of your service ?

Comment: I've tried with and without it and I get the same error either way so no I'm not sure but it doesn't make a difference whether its there or not.